# Calculate distance traveled by a vehicle in sumo with traCI4Matlab

Tags: matlab, sumo, vehicle-routing, traffic-simulation

I need some help: I'm trying to calculate the distance traveled by a vehicle I added in TRACI4Matlab in a SUMO scenario at the end of the simulation.

With my code I can calculate the distance but once passed the last node, since there is no more my vehicle in the SUMO scenario the error is thrown:
`Error: Answered with error to command 0xa4: Vehicle 'prova' is not known.`
this is my MATLAB code:

```
clear
close all
clc

import traci.constants


[scenarioPath,~,~] = fileparts(which(mfilename));
cd(scenarioPath);

traci.start('sumo-gui -c ./scenario1.sumocfg --start');

SIM_STEPS = [0 1000];
beginTime = SIM_STEPS(1);
duration =  SIM_STEPS(2);
endTime =  SIM_STEPS(1) +  SIM_STEPS(2) - 1;

traci.vehicle.add('prova', 'percorso1', depart='100')

for i = 1 : duration
    id{i}=(traci.vehicle.getIDList());
    d1(i)=traci.vehicle.getDistance('prova');
    traci.simulation.step();
end


traci.close()
```

How can I continue the simulation or avoid the error?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get information via traci about a vehicle which is not in the simulation anymore. You could add a stop to the end of the route or just store the last distance you noticed. A different way of getting total route length would be to generate XML output for instance [tripinfo](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/Output/TripInfo.html) and parse it.